# How to implement facebook pixel in flutter in 2024 any example?

Tags: flutter, facebook, package, facebook-pixel

I think I'm on the right track by adding the packages:

**  facebook_app_events: 0.19.1
flutter_login_facebook: 1.9.0**
**
But I would like to know if anyone has done it with Flutter and PixelFacebook?**

example with the facebook pixel in flutter
thanks for helps!!!